# Cannot update into MongoDB database using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to update into database. Seems like there are no data inserted altough the console.log message are displayed correctly.

```
router.post('/find_teacher',function(req,res){

  // update Data
  var updateData={
    replacement: req.body.replacement,
    flag:1,
  };
  var message='Data has been not updated';
  Timetable_relief.updateOne({_id:req.params.id},updateData,{upsert: true},function(err,numrows){
      if(!err){
        console.log(updateData);
        console.log('Replacement Are Created');
        res.redirect('/timetable_relief');
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: Your code seems fine can you print req.params.id and check whether you are recieveing this id or not

Comment: it was undefined @Anku

Comment: Yeah that is why i think it is not working

Comment: i think is should use router.post('/find_teacher/:id'.... instead

Comment: Yes i have added answer to it please upvote if you find it useful

Answer (score 1):

If you need id from route you need to define route like below

```
 router.post('/find_teacher/:id',function(req,res){

  // update Data
  var updateData={
    replacement: req.body.replacement,
    flag:1,
  };
  var message='Data has been not updated';
  Timetable_relief.updateOne({_id:req.params.id},updateData,{upsert: true},function(err,numrows){
      if(!err){
        console.log(updateData);
        console.log('Replacement Are Created');
        res.redirect('/timetable_relief');
      }
  });
});
```

here your req.params.id is  undefined that is why mongodb query is not working